# Deactivating CSS styling

Tags: html, css

I am working on this HTML document and am applying a CSS counter like this:

```
ol {
    list-style-type:none;
    counter-reset: nested;
}
li::before {
    counter-increment: nested;
    content: counters(nested, '.') '. ';
}
```

This allows me to have sub lists like (1.1, 1.2 ...).

The problem is that page layout is being applied to my HTML document in the web application and CSS styling continues being applied to that layout.

Is there any way to "tell" it to stop applying its style after `</html>` is reached so no matter what layout is being added to my document it will stay as is.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: you can use nested selector to apply the style only to the lists you want. e.g. `.myList li::before`

Comment: Hi gp. thanks for speedy reply. Even with nested selector it won't stop applying the style. I tried ID selector
{
    <style type = "text/CSS">
    #counter_area
    </style>
}
and than marked the part I want style to be applied by
{
    <div class = "counter_zone" id = "counter_area">
    whatever code goes inside
    </div>
}
it still applies the style to the remaining (it just changes the counter to 1. 1. 1.)

T.

Comment: You can add a class (like @gp. said) then remove it with `element.classList.remove('myList')`